# transition for translateY(0) working, but not translateY(-50px)

Tags: css, transform, transition, tic-tac-toe

I'm having some trouble with a transition on a transform. I'm making a tic-tac-toe game like in the freecodecamp front-end challenges: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/KzXQgy.

I've been able to create most layout things no problem, but am having an issue with my transition on a div that shows which players' turn it is after hitting the reset button. Right now I'm just working on two player mode, so I click two players, then X or O, and then the tic-tac-toe board shows up and a div transform: translateY(-50px) to indicate whether it's Player 1 or Player 2's turn (based on a random number variable I set up). The first time through the div transition's perfectly. Then I hit the Reset All div and it takes me back to the beginning to choose how many players again. And the div transitions the transform: translateY(0) perfectly back to it's starting position. Where I'm struggling is, now when I cycle through the options again, if it's Player 1 or Player 2's turn again, the transition never happens and the div just transforms -50px up with the translateY.

I've tried everything I could think of, JS setting up the transition, resetting the transition, moving the transition to be on different classes, adding and removing a class that only has a transition on it. Can't figure it out, but the weird thing is, whenever I hit the "Reset All", the transform transitions back to 0px normally. Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/rorschach1234/pen/dZMaJg?editors=0111. I know it's still very rough, but just can't figure out this transition problem. Really appreciate any help. Thanks everyone!

My relevant Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="turns">
    <div class="turns__left turns__box"></div>
    <div class="turns__right turns__box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My relevant CSS:

```
.turns {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  &__box {
    width: 40%;
    height: 50px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transition: transform 1s .3s ease;
  }

  &__left {
    background-color: $color-turn-left;
    //transition: transform 1s .3s ease;
  }

  &__right {
    background-color: $color-turn-right;
    //transition: transform 1s .3s ease;
  }
}
```

My Javascript:

```
let numOfPlayers = document.querySelectorAll(".player .choices h2");
let playerScreen = document.querySelector(".player");
let markerScreen = document.querySelector(".markers");
let singlePlayer = true;
let backBtn = document.querySelector(".markers__back");
let gameScreen = document.querySelector(".game");
let playerOne; let playerTwo; let activePlayer;
let turnBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".turns__box");
let resetBtn = document.querySelector(".scoreboard__reset");

game();

function game() {
  playerModeSelection();
  markerSelection();
}

function boardChange(active, inactive) {
  inactive.style.opacity = "0";
  inactive.style.zIndex = "0";
  active.style.opacity = "1";
  active.style.zIndex = "1"; 
}


//One or Two player Selection & transition to Marker Selector
function playerModeSelection() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfPlayers.length; i++) {
    numOfPlayers[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(i === 1) {
      singlePlayer = false;
    }
    boardChange(markerScreen, playerScreen);
    }) 
   }
}

function markerSelection() {

  //Back Button Functionality
    backBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    boardChange(playerScreen, markerScreen); 
  })

  //Listen for choice of X or O
  for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++) {
    markers[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    boardChange(gameScreen, markerScreen);
    if (i === 1) {
      playerArr = ["O", "X"];
    }
    //Starts Two Player Game; Here begin is the function that calls transition
    if(!singlePlayer) {
      twoPlayerMode();
    }
    })
  }
}


function twoPlayerMode() {
  activePlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  turnBoxes[activePlayer].textContent = "Go Player " + (activePlayer + 1) + "!";
  turnBoxes[activePlayer].style.transform = "translateY(-50px)";
  resetBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    boardChange(playerScreen, gameScreen);
    turnBoxes[activePlayer].style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
  })
}
```

Comment: are you trying to do transform: translate(0px, 10px); ?

Comment: Hopefully I didn't confuse anyone. What I want is for the transition to work when I click "reset all" and then click through to the game board again. The "Go Player 1" "Go Player 2" div's nicely transform with the transition the first time through, but there's no transition the second time I click through. The "Go Player 1" or "Go Player 2" just appears any time after the first click-through.

Comment: So I think I've narrowed it down to my activePlayer variable (the variable creating a random number of either 0 or 1) is not working properly because it's in the for loops and creating multiple values each cycle through the playerModeSelection and markerSelection functions. So I need to come up with a way to assign a random variable for who goes first and then use that variable as the index for which div should be translated.